# incorrect datetime value during import of dump on MySQL 8 from 5.7

Tags: mysql

I am doing a mysqldump on MySQL 5.7 Ubuntu 16.04 and a zcat import into MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

After a few imports the import stops and throws the following error:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 317: Incorrect datetime value: '2014-03-30 02:00:35' for column 'timestamp' at row 2539
```

There is another similar one:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '2006-03-26 02:04:31'
```

Both are aparently time zone changes for summer time +1h

There seems to be a problem with the time zone aparently after doing some research, but everything looks good:

old server:

```
 date
Sun May 30 16:28:56 CEST 2021
```

new server:

```
date
Sun May 30 16:23:43 CEST 2021
```

In fact the table shema shows "timestamp" instead of datetime:

```
timestamp Index timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT_GENERATED ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I am not sure why, but the date is 2014 and there might be historic reasons for it.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values to local time zone when you read it, and converts to UTC when you store it. On these two servers try to select theses values with a `SET @@time_zone = '+00:00';` before.
Probrably you'll need to force a sync on these two servers with a NTP server, this little difference in time happens when a machine stay a long time without synchronizing.

Comment: @HectorVido How can I check the time zones on those servers ? I believe the old one is set to UTC but can not remember how/where. A simple date command shows current time.

Comment: 2014-03-30 was a Daylight Saving Time change time day in most countries.

Comment: @merlin a simple `date` command will show. I'll live in Brazil, the result is `Sun May 30 11:49:47 AM -03 2021`.
Also, check if your `mysqldump` (or force) is usign a option `--tz-utc`, this is default but, who knows...

Comment: `timedatectl` shows more information.

Comment: @forpas I believe the server was running in a different time zone setting in 2014. Any chance to import this dump?

Comment: I have also added --tz-utc to the mysqldump command now and tried a fresh dump. Same result on importing.

Comment: These two machines are with the same date/time?